# Is it possible to change a :root variable permanently using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a button to get a prompt on my admin page on a website I'm making and I noticed that the color does change when I submit it, but when I refresh it does not change permanently, is there a way to do that with javascript?

JS

```
const root = document.querySelector(':root');

function changeColor(){
    var color = window.prompt("Enter your color: ");
    root.style.setProperty('--clr-primary', color);
    
}
```

CSS

```
:root {
    --clr-text: white;
    --clr-secondary-text: yellow;
    --clr-primary: #098ef6;
    --clr-background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    --border-color: white;
    --clr-bg-border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
    
    --ff-primary: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;
    --ff-global: 'Staatliches', cursive;
    
}
```

HTML

```
        <h1>Input to change primary colors (header, footer, service borders)</h1>
        <button class="colorChange" onclick="changeColor()">Change Color</button>
        <br></br>
```

Comment: When you refresh the page, a completely new window is built from whatever the server sends back to the browser. If you want to remember the new color, you'll have to store that in the browser (local storage) or on your server, depending on how you want your application to work.

Comment: @Pointy I'm more or so looking for it to be a dynamic website, to a point where I have an admin panel and I can change stuff throughout the website from that admin panel permanently.

Comment: OK, then you'll need your server-side database to keep track of the details, and make sure that when a page is loaded the appropriate configuration goes with it. This is all normal stuff for a web application but it's not something that has a simple standard solution. It's something you'll have to design and develop for yourself.

Comment: Alright thank you, I appreciate it, I was thinking it would be a database solution, just gonna have to figure out a way to do that.